# Delphi 2006: Run-time assignment of PNG to TImage loses alpha transparency

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-2006, timage, alpha-transparency

Delphi 2006's TImage doesn't quite support PNGs.  In order to have images with alpha transparency on my forms I have to load them at run-time.  I can load them at design time but they don't survive, I think because PNGs are not saved in the DFM file.  I'm sure this is all hunky-dory in the latest Delphi but I can't upgrade right at the moment.

Anyway, I was loading them at run-time with:

```
Image1.Picture.Assign (PngImageCollection1.Items [0].PNGImage) ;
```

The PNGImageCollection component holds all my PNGs of various sizes (these are created and loaded at design-time), and I assign them to the respective TImages in the FormCreate event.

This has worked OK, until I had a problem where I was trying to reuse one of these images somewhere else after it had been used on a form.  I discovered that the act of assigning the TPicture had set it to an empty image as a result of the Assign.  This was happening in the routine TPicture.ForceType, which AFAICT checks the type of FGraphic, and if it is not the desired type, it frees FGraphic and creates a new instance of the requested type.

OK.  So after a bit of scratching around, I see that maybe I should really be doing this:

```
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign (PngImageCollection1.Items [0].PNGImage) ;
```

This did the trick, in that the Assign did not clobber the image, but the image now shows with the semi-transparent bits as opaque, i.e.:

[image: TImage when assigned with Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign]

instead of:

[image: TImage when assigned with Image1.Picture.Assign]

How can I get this image to display the alpha-transparent bits properly? (and supplementary question: Is Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign the correct way to do it?).

Here's the code in a bit more detail:

In the code where I had the problem "reusing" a TImage, the sequence was:
On form create:

```
LogoImage.Picture.Assign (PngImageCollection1.Items [0].PNGImage) ;
```

(PNGIMage is a company logo, LogoImage1 is on the main form).

On print report header:

```
procedure PrintLogo (Report : TBaseReport) ;

var
    X1, Y1, LogoHeightMM    : Double ;

begin
with Report do
    begin
    LogoHeightMM  := CalcGraphicHeight (LogoWidthMM, MainForm.LogoImage.Picture.Graphic) ;
    X1            := PageWidth - MarginRight - LogoWidthMM ;
    Y1            := SectionBottom - LogoHeightMM ;
    PrintBitmapRect (X1, Y1, X1 + LogoWidthMM, Y1 + LogoHeightMM, MainForm.LogoImage.Picture.Bitmap) ;
    end ;
end ;
```

The first time the routine to print the logo is called it executes without error, but the LogoImage .Picture is left cleared after the call to PrintBitmapRect.  The next time the print header routine is called, the call to CalcGraphicHeight fails because the width and height of the image are zero.

Changing the Picture.Assign to a Picture.Bitmap.Assign fixes the RTE in the header print routine, but when I transplanted the same "fix" to other static images assigned from PNGs (like the gears above) I lost the aplha channel.

Comment: I suggest giving up one of the tags on the question in favor of `Delphi`. There should be developers who have used previous versions in the past but not watching their tags currently..

Comment: Best is to try to reproduce in a very small test case, then work from there. It helps a lot if you can post that small test case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not showing the really relevant part of your code: how are you re-using the image that would cause it to have a particular type.

When you assign a TImage a TPngObject, the graphic of the image holds a png object. Only when you request specifically a bitmap, it will force its graphic to be of a bitmap type. For instance, this,

```
  Bmp.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
```

will force Image1 to have a bitmap graphic, if its graphic was a png object it will be freed. While this,

```
  Bmp.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
```

will not force Image1 to have a bitmap graphic, the png object will carry out the assignment and stay there.

Delphi's bitmaps (at least up to recent versions), do not support alpha-channels, so you shouldn't be using `Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(..` for partially transparent images.

BTW, instead of re-using the graphic in the image, you could probably use the image in your png image collection as the source..

Comment: @rossmcm - It is the `PrintBitmapRect(..` line that's causing your image to loose the png object, because you're requesting specifically a bitmap: `MainForm.LogoImage.Picture.Bitmap`. It is exactly the kind of first example as in the answer. If 'PrintBitmapRect' requires a bitmap, create a temporary bitmap, set its size, assign to it by using the second example as in the answer, pass to 'PrintBitmapRect', then free the temporary bitmap.

Comment: That worked.  Many thanks.  I find 3rd party PNG support very fragile and fragmented.  I think it might be worth biting the bullet and shelling out for a current version of Delphi so I can dispose of this mishmash of PNG support - do you know of a reasonable suite of PNG units all from the one place?

Comment: @rossmcm - I figured so when you accepted the answer, :) you're welcome!... No, I guess we're using the same library, with the possible exception that I also have Martijn Saly's extensions, like the TPngImageList. I can't find them on the internet any more but Uwe Raabe's D2009 port is still available at http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26127 . Ultimately I strongly agree that it would be best to have them with the VCL, but I guess I'll wait for the 64 bits..